# TensorRT multiple Threads

Tags: multithreading, cuda, pycuda, tensorrt, nvidia-docker

I am trying to use TensorRt using the python API. I am trying to use it in multiple threads where the Cuda context is used with all the threads (everything works fine in a single thread). I am using docker with tensorrt:20.06-py3 image, and an onnx model, and Nvidia 1070 GPU.

The multiple thread approach should be allowed, as mentioned here [TensorRT Best Practices](https://docs.nvidia.com/deeplearning/tensorrt/best-practices/index.html#thread-safety).

I created the context in the main thread:

```
cuda.init()
device = cuda.Device(0)
ctx = device.make_context()
```

I tried two methods, first to build the engine in the main thread and use it in the execution thread. This case gives this error.

```
[TensorRT] ERROR: ../rtSafe/cuda/caskConvolutionRunner.cpp (373) - Cask Error in checkCaskExecError<false>: 10 (Cask Convolution execution)
[TensorRT] ERROR: FAILED_EXECUTION: std::exception
```

Second, I tried to build the model in the thread it gives me this error:

```
pycuda._driver.LogicError: explicit_context_dependent failed: invalid device context - no currently active context?
```

The error appears when I call 'cuda.Stream()'

I am sure that I can run multiple Cuda streams in parallel under the same Cuda context, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: You will need to explicitly pass and bind to the context in each thread

Comment: can you tell me how to do it? I know there is a cuCtxSetCurrent function in C but I cannot do similar actions in pycuda/python

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. The idea is to create a normal global `ctx = device.make_context()` Then in each execution thread do a:

```
ctx.push()
---
Execute Inference Code
---
ctx.pop()
```

The link for the source and full sample is [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/how-to-use-tensorrt-by-the-multi-threading-package-of-python/123085)